# How to Scrape table from Python Beautifulsoup/API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape table from https://www.cnbc.com/sector-etfs/

I used code something like below but didn't work..

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.cnbc.com/sector-etfs/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table')
pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

I also tried requests.get function to get the data but couldn't convert to table format. Can you please help me on how to scrape the data in a table format? That would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no tables in page source code. Data comes from XHR. Try below to get data:

```
import requests

url = 'https://quote.cnbc.com/quote-html-webservice/quote.htm?noform=1&partnerId=2&fund=1&exthrs=0&output=json&symbolType=issue&symbols=289752|289759|289840|289776|136746|289783|289847|289856|289812|289745|5064448|171658|4114925|4733797|281752|21583731|171610|42634418|5064445|5064446|42634422|151687|3585851|5064447|29549437&requestMethod=extended'
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned, I already tried this way.. Is there a way that I can get the data in dataframe format?

Comment: @Steve.Kim , data comes as JSON. Not like a *dataframe format*. You need to convert it to format you like, just like a JavaScript does on web-clients side. As your question doesn't sound like *"How to convert JSON to HTML table"*, try to create new question for this issue